# Bathroom light switch turns off kitchen light randomly

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

My kitchen and bathroom share a wall. The switches in both rooms are not set up in an intentional 3-way switch setup.

If my kitchen light switch is on, turning the bathroom switch to either on or off will sometimes cause the kitchen light to go out.

The kitchen light switch then needs to be turned to off and on again to light back up.

What should I be worried about? I tried explaining this to an electrician but since he couldn't recreate the problem, he dismissed it. It's now happening more frequently.

Comment: Are the switches in question wired using the side-screws or backstabs?

Comment: I would be concerned, are the smart ? WiFi ? switches  just standard switches sounds like a loose wire nut or backstab.

Comment: Backstabs detected.  You could know for sure by getting an AFCI breaker. If it's a failing backstab connection, it would trip.